# How to make sticked navbar full width i.e. without scrollbar

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.navbar{
background:lightseagreen;
height:25px;
position:sticky;
top:0;
}

.grida{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:70fr 30fr;
grid-column-gap:3%;
min-height:100vh;
}

.gridaa{background:gold;}
.gridab{background:silver;}

.footer{
background:lightseagreen;
min-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar'></div>
<div class='grida'>
<div class='gridaa'></div>
<div class='gridab'></div>
</div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

So `navbar` is not scrollable and I don't need the scrollbar on its right side.

How to push the scrollbar 25px down and make `navbar` full width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow: hidden; /* disable body overflow this will enable */
}                 /* navbar to have full width without */
                  /* scrollbar */
.navbar{
background:lightseagreen;
height:25px;
position:sticky;
top:0;
}

.grida{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:70fr 30fr;
grid-column-gap:3%;
height:100vh;
overflow: auto; /* here you can set overflow of your content */ }               /*container   */
 

.gridaa{background:gold;height:500px;}
.gridab{background:silver;height:500px;}

.footer{
background:lightseagreen;
height:150px;
grid-column: 1/3;
grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar'></div>
<div class='grida'>
  <div class='gridaa'></div> <!-- move content into block -->
  <div class='gridab'></div> <!-- which will have overflow  -->
  <div class='footer'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can at least highlight the code you added to help us understand what you did

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you want this

```
.grida {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 70fr 30fr;
 grid-column-gap: 3%
 height: calc(100vh - 75px);
}
```